# Ensuring Uniqueness for a sorted set in redis

Tags: redis

I am trying to store media objects and have them retrievable by a certain time range through redis. I have chosen a sorted set data type to do this. I am adding elements like:

```
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355264694
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355248565
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355209157
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355208992
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355208888
zAdd: key: media:552672 score: 1355208815
```

Where key is unique to the location id the media was taken at and the score is the creation time of the media object. And the value is a json_decode of the media object.

When I go to retrieve using `zRevRangeByScore`, occasionally there will be duplicate entries. I'm essentially using Redis as a buffer to an external API, if the users are making the same API call twice with X seconds, then I will retrieve the results from the cache, otherwise, I will add it to the cache, not checking to see if it already exists due to the definition of a set not containing duplicates.
Possible known issues:
If the media object attribute changes between caching it will show up as a duplicate

Is there a better way to store this type of data without doing checks on the redis client side?

**TLDR;**
What is the best way to store and retrieve objects in Redis where you can select a range of objects by timestamp and ensure that they are unique?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lets make sure we're talking about the same things, so here is the terminology for Redis sorted sets:

```
ZADD key score member [score] [member]
summary: Add one or more members to a sorted set, or update its score if it already exists
```

- `key` - the 'name' of the sorted set
- `score` - the score (in our case a timestamp)
- `member` - the string the score is associated with
- A sorted set has many members, each with a score

It sounds like your are using a JSON encoded string of the object as the member. The member is what is unique in a sorted set. As you say, if the object changes it will be added as a new member to the sorted set. That is probably not what you  want.

A sorted set is the Redis way to store data by timestamp, but the member that is stored in the set is usually a 'pointer' to another key in Redis.

From your description I think you want this data structure:

- A sorted set storing all media by created timestamp
- A string or hash for each unique media

I recommend storing the media objects in a hash as this allows more flexibility.
Example:

```
# add some members to our sorted set
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD media 1000 media:1 1003 media:2 1001 media:3
(integer) 3
# create hashes for our members
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET media:1 id 1 name "media one" content "content string for one"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET media:2 id 2 name "media two" content "content string for two"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET media:3 id 3 name "media three" content "content string for three"
OK
```

There are two ways to retrieve data stored in this way. If you need to get members within specific timestamp ranges (eg: last 7 days) you will have to use `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` to retrieve the members, then loop through those to fetch each hash with `HGETALL` or similar. See [pipelining](http://www.redis.io/topics/pipelining) to see how you can do the loop with one call to the server.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGEBYSCORE media +inf -inf
1) "media:2"
2) "media:3"
3) "media:1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL media:2
1) "id"
2) "2"
3) "name"
4) "media two"
5) "content"
6) "content string for two"
```

If you only want to get the last n members (or eg: 10th most recent to 100th most recent) you can use `SORT` to get items. See the [sort documentation](http://www.redis.io/commands/sort) for syntax and how to retrieve different hash fields, limit the results and other options.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SORT media BY nosort GET # GET *->name GET *->content1) DESC
1) "media:2"
2) "media two"
3) "content string for two"
4) "media:3"
5) "media three"
6) "content string for three"
7) "media:1"
8) "media one"
9) "content string for one"
```

**NB:** sorting a sorted hash by score (`BY nosort`) only works from Redis 2.6.

If you plan on getting media for the last day, week, month, etc. I would recommend using a seperate sorted set for each one and use `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` to remove old members. You can then just use `SORT` on these sorted sets to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for an exact thing. One quick question: I have a situation where I do not want duplicates, so I am checking them in my sorted set and then adding them and creating the hash. I just wanted to ask if it is an overkill?